# Wordpress doesn't recognise created theme

Tags: themes, css

I just started creating new theme in wordpress, I got the html/css, I put the heading in css like usual:

```
/*
Theme Name: Your Theme Name
Theme URI: http://your-theme-homepage.com
Description: Oh what a lovely description of your theme you'll put here!
Author: Your Name
Author URI: http://your-website.com
Template: If this is a child theme, you'll set the template theme's folder name here
Version: 3.1
Any general information, license statements, plugin requirements, or any other information you
      might want to share.


*/
```

and html site in the same directory.

Wordpress doesn't recognise the theme and I get error like

> Broken Themes
>
> The following themes are installed but incomplete. Themes must have a
>   stylesheet and a template.
>
> Name  Description Wp_theme    Stylesheet is missing.

or something similar.

What is EXACTLY the requirement for wordpress to register theme in directory? Is it just css heading or something else must be added?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, drop the `Template: ...` line. Your problem is almost certainly that your stylesheet is not named style.css

Comment: Template dropped, stylesheet named style.css, now I don't get any errors, but template is not recognised anyway. Like I didn't put anything in the folder.

Comment: Do you have index.php?

Comment: The Codex is your friend: **[Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)**